# Multiple unwanted instances of application start after clicking dock icon

Tags: applications, desktop, processes

When I click on a dock icon, sometimes multiple instances of an application start.
For example:

element+   19606   19402  0 Dec29 pts/2    00:00:00 locate blender
element+   21772       1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 bwrap --args 42 blender
element+   21783   21772  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 bwrap --args 42 blender
element+   21784   21783  0 Dec29 ?        00:06:10 ./blender
element+   32891   13701  0 18:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto blender

How can I prevent this?

ETA:
Linux Lenovo-Y50-70-9bafae1a 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Blender version 4.0.2